# Named anchor in URL upsets IIS server and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

When sent from a browser as we know named anchor is not part of GET

http://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/osfi/index_e.aspx?articleid=166#warningnotices

Just wondering if scrape this page from the code with the anchor in url ( left accidentally )

```
oxmlhttp = createobject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
oxmlhttp.open('GET', "http://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/osfi/index_e.aspx?articleid=166#warningnotices", .t.)
oxmlhttp.send()
```

what causes such a painful reaction, as in a code ( oxmlhttp.ResponseBody ) we  receive back a page :

extract from response
"We are experiencing technical difficulties with our Web site. Normal service should resume shortly. We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your understanding".

Answer (score 2):

Is this page yours?

If not, then the developer of the page may have / have not implemented a check to handle #.

To me the error message sounds as if it is a generic error handler when an unhandled exception occurs.

Comment: If it were my page, I wouldn't have asked. It is The Office of the Superintendent of Financial Institutions Canada (OSFI) website.